# Canvas: "object is undefined"

Tags: typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to create a line in Canvas. Everything was going well until I got stuck on this part:

```js
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "chart.js/auto";
import { Chart, ChartData, ChartDataset, ChartOptions } from "chart.js";

function DoughnutChart(){
  const doughnutLabelsLine = {
    id: "doughnutLabelsLine",
    afterDraw(chart: Chart<"doughnut">, args: any, options: ChartOptions) {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea: { top, bottom, left, right, width, height },
      } = chart;

      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
        // console.log(chart.getDatasetMeta(i));
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach((datapoint, index) => {
          console.log(dataset);
          const { x, y } = datapoint.tooltipPosition();
          //Object is possibly undefined
          ctx.fillStyle = dataset?.borderColor[index];
          ctx.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);
        });
      });
    },
  };

//config...
//dataDoughnut

return (
        <div className="col-span-6">
          <Doughnut
            data={dataDoughnut}
            options={config}
            width={200}
            height={300}
            plugins={[doughnutLabelsLine]}
          />
        </div>
);
}
export default DoughnutChart;
```

I have tried putting it into an if statement as well and using an exclamation mark, but that didn't work.
Am I missing something here?

Edit: Made an adjustment based on user2057925's suggestion

DoughnutLabelsLine

```js
  const doughnutLabelsLine = {
    id: "doughnutLabelsLine",
    afterDraw(chart: Chart<"doughnut">, args: any, options: ChartOptions) {
      const {
        ctx,
        chartArea: { top, bottom, left, right, width, height },
      } = chart;

      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
        // console.log(chart.getDatasetMeta(i));
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach((datapoint, index) => {
          console.log(dataset);
          const { x, y } = datapoint.tooltipPosition();
          ctx.save();
          const borderColor = datapoint.options.borderColor as
            | string
            | CanvasGradient
            | CanvasPattern;
          ctx.fillStyle = borderColor;
          // ctx.fillStyle = dataset?.borderColor[index];
          ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
          ctx.restore();
        });
      });
    },
  };
```

Comment: I think the undefined is not for dataset but for borderColor. Can you publish the chart datasets configuration that you are using?

Comment: Anyway you could the datapoint.options.borderColor, you shouldn't need either the dataset  instance or the index

Comment: Using the datapoint you will also have the vantage that if you don't define any borderColor, the datapoint (element) will provide you in the options the default value. In the dataset you don't have the default. Codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/oNdBjVG

Comment: I've tried your solution, but mine stays white. Because I'm working with typescript, I had to type borderColor first. I'll make an edit with what I have right now.

Comment: What is the error? That's just the message, but we need to see the full error because it tells you what can be undefined and why you can't do it.

Comment: @user2057925 Had a small type somewhere. It works! Can you post it as an answer? So I can mark it as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `undefined` error is not related to the `dataset` instance but due to the  `borderColor` one.

Anyway the best thing could be to use the `datapoint.options.borderColor` because:

1. you shouldn't need either the dataset instance or the index
2. the datapoint, being an `ArcElement`, provides in `options` node all its options, even if they are configured (using default).

```js
const p = {
    id: "doughnutLabelsLine",
    afterDraw(chart, args, options) {
      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach((datapoint, index) => {
          const { x, y } = datapoint.tooltipPosition();
          ctx.save();
          ctx.fillStyle = datapoint.options.borderColor;
          ctx.fillRect(x -5, y - 5, 10, 10);
          ctx.restore();
        });
      });
    }
};

const config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    plugins: [p],  
    data: {
      labels: [6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Simple treemap',
        data: [6, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1],
        borderColor: ['red', 'blue']
      }]
    },
  };
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```